# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with EventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following piece of code on which I am getting warning two warnings:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

> unmountComponentAtNode(): The node you're attempting to unmount was rendered by another copy of React.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import GravatarList from "./GravatarList";
    import Header from "./Header";
    import { calculateNumberOfImages } from "./utils";
    
    const App = () => {
      const handle = () => {
        setState({ images: calculateNumberOfImages() });
      }
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
          return () => {
    
            window.removeEventListener('resize', () => handle())
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => handle())
          }
       }, [])
    
    
      const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
        
        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => handle());
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => handle());
      
        return { images: calculateNumberOfImages() };
      });
    
      return (
        <div>
          
          <Header />
          <GravatarList state={state} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong as I have already cleared the listeners in `useEffect`.

Comment: Why are you adding the listeners inside `useState()`? This seems odd to me.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is that the event callbacks you are trying to remove ***aren't*** the same callbacks you added to begin with. The issue is because you are using anonymous functions to call the function updating state.

You should also not use the state initializer function to do side effects like adding event listeners.

Move the `handle` callback and adding of event listeners into the mounting `useEffect` hook. Pass the `handle` callback reference to the add/remove functions,

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => ({
    images: calculateNumberOfImages()
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    const handle = () => {
      setState({ images: calculateNumberOfImages() });
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handle);
    window.addEventListener("resize", handle);
  
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handle);
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handle);
    }
   }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <GravatarList state={state} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am getting the same error even after putting the callbacks in useEffect.

Comment: @DanyalShahid Make sure to kill any running development servers and do a clear cache/hard reload of the browser to ensure there are no running instances of the callbacks running on the `window` object. Also, that is only a warning about the state update, not an error.

Comment: I think react discourage using window.event listener like that, there must be a library to these things.

Comment: @DanyalShahid React doesn't discourage global event listeners on `window` like this that I've ever seen, how else would one listen for the window being scrolled or resized? React *does* discourage using query selectors to access the DOM, preferring use of React refs. And it prefers directly attaching `onScroll` or `onClick` directly on the DOM elements if rendering locally in the component.